# Passing method result as argument to other method

Tags: python, class, methods

I want a method to accept the result of another method as an argument:

```
def method2(self, self.method1(arg_for_method_1))
    pass
```

but I keep getting the error

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Why?

Comment: Remember, the arguments you request are *inputs* to your function.  Invoking a method that you are asking for while requesting it as an input doesn't seem very consistent and thus isn't allowed in a definition.  Luckily, putting that logic in the body of the definition is totally allowed! (This ignores optional arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to supply a value where Python expects a simple name; that name will be assigned a value at runtime.

Since `self` is already an argument, you can probably just call `self.method1()` when `method2` is run:

```
def method2(self)
    x = self.method1()
```

If you want the default value for a parameter to be set by `method1`, use `None` as a default value.

```
def method2(self, var=None):
    if var is None:
        var = self.method1()
```

Comment: Default arguments are quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
class XYZ:
   def some_method(self):
      return math.PI
   def method1(self,x):
      return x**0.5
   def method2(self, method1):# <- this is the argument ... not the value
      print method1()
   def method3(self,some_value):
      print some_value

x = XYZ()
x.method2(x.some_method)
x.method3(x.method1(5))   #<--- you call the method when you pass it not when you define it
```

Comment: But there is an optional argument to method 1, I'll clarify the original.